# How do I optimize font files? or how to load faster

Tags: html, css, fonts

When I upload font files like Google fonts from my server it gets at least 300 kb. Is it possible to compress these files without destroying them?

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Bold';
    src : url('fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'regular';
    src : url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'semibold';
    src : url('fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf');
}
```

[İmage Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt5CR.jpg)

Comment: before asking we expect you have done some research to fix your problem... If you search 'fonts load faster' on google for example, you will find a lot of resource

Comment: Rather than compressing the current "best way" seems to be to chunk them by [unicode-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range). This way the browser loads only the chunk it needs to display the glyphs on the page. (Not sure it's the "best", but it's at least what Google's CDN does.) but if you are really loading OpenSans, why not link directly to Google's CDN? You are not the only one using these fonts, chances are great your users will already have it cached. And finally don't forget the `local()` before any `url()`.